# Launching wine program from launcher not working

Tags: gnome, 13.10, wine

Would love some help. I'm trying to create a working launcher for photoshop. I've got it installed and working. I can launch the program using...

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Photoshop/Photoshop.exe
```

The terminal spits out a ton of fun stuff, the photoshop logo comes up, and it works just like it does on my windows machine, text tool and everything : ) then I close it, and try to open it from the launcher icon I created (ubuntu gnome 13.10 btw), and I get nothing, just a spinning wheel in the toolbar up top. Here's my photoshop.desktop file...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Photoshop
Comment=Photoshop
Exec=sh c "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Photoshop/Photoshop.exe"
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/photoshop.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;Graphics;
StartupNotify=true
```

Any help would rock!

Comment: Try replacing  `Exec=sh c "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Photoshop/Photoshop.exe"`  with `Exec=sh c "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Photoshop; wine Photoshop.exe"`

Comment: Tried... no luck : (

Comment: Sorry. I have'n read it carefully. I think `Exec=sh c` should be `Exec=sh -c` instead.

Comment: You rock! That worked : ) so -c is an option, got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make an official answer:

Try replacing

```
Exec=sh c "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Photoshop/Photoshop.exe"
```

with

```
Exec=sh -c "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Photoshop; wine Photoshop.exe"
```